# Cannot debug MAUI on my Android phone via WiFi

Tags: android, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, maui

Since the Android device emulator that comes with Visual Studio [never works](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Android-emulator-cannot-start/1610887) for me and Microsoft won't fix it (or release their fix, which is the same to me), I'm trying to debug my apps on my Android phone directly. (Sooner or later I'd need to do that anyway.) I'd like to use the WiFi debugging option because my USB port is usually dust-protected and I don't want to take off the cover every time.

I followed [these instructions](https://www.xamarinexpert.it/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-and-say-goodbye-to-cables/) and could pair the device to my computer (it's also listed on the phone now), but connecting fails. The command says: The connection was refused by the target computer. (Translated to English myself) Nothing more.

What is the issue and what can I do? Are there better instructions available that don't involve typing in magic commands? I see all sorts of remote support for iOS directly in Visual Studio but nothing for Android except the broken emulator. (I have nothing to do with Apple products, so I'm not interested in that.)

I have just upgraded to the latest Visual Studio 2022 17.2.0 Preview 1.0 on Windows 10 on a Surface Pro 4. My Android device is a Samsung S10e with the latest updates and Android 12. There is no network security software installed, just the basic features that come with Android and Windows already.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry for my bad English language level!
And upgrade Visual Studio to 17.3.1!

As you know you must turn on the Wireless debugging option on the phone, in this option check the phone's IP address and port.
for example "192.168.1.5:2244"
now enable this port by flowing steps:

1. connect the phone to VS by USB cable (configuration for the first
   time)
2. check and see the phone in the "Android local devices" list.
3. open Tools > Android > Android Adb Command Prompt...
4. set TCP/IP port to the phone's active port

   adb tcpip 2244
5. now disconnect the phone
6. connect to the phone via WiFi from Android Adb Command Prompt

   adb connect 192.168.1.5:2244

**Attention: after trying to connect, the device promotes to connect, accept it and if the connection was failed, retry step 6**
Now you can see the phone in the "Android local devices" list again.